# How can I test a 403 error?

Tags: django, unit-testing, http-status-code-403, http-error

I have a Test Class, that test the access of all page with different user.

Those access are defined by decorator on each of my views.

*views.py :*

```
@login_required
def afficher(request):
    ...
    ...

@creation_permission_required
def ajouter(request):
    ...
    ...
```

Some of these decorator are defined by me.

*decorators.py :*

```
def creation_permission_required(function):
    @wraps(function)
    @login_required
    def decorateur(request, *k, **a):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username__iexact=request.user.username)
        if user.is_superuser or user.get_profile().creation:
            return function(request, *k, **a)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("non_autorise"))# <--- PROBLEM
    return decorateur
    return function
```

When I test them, I use the status_code attribute to verify if the user can access or not the page

*test.py :*

```
c = Client()
c.login(username='aucun', password='aucun')
for url in self.url_aucun:
    r = c.get(reverse(url['url'], args=url['args']))
    self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 200)
for url in self.url_creation:
    r = c.get(reverse(url['url'], args=url['args']))
    self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 302)      # <--- SECOND PROBLEM
```

When a user doesn't have the right to access a page, the page should return a 403 error (forbidden). How can I do to test 403 instead of 302 ?

EDIT : I tried to use HttpResponseForbidden(reverse("non_autorise")), but couldn't get any content. So then I tried to make my own HttpResponse which is an exact copy of HttpResponseRedirect but with another status_code (403) still didn't get any content...

*decorators.py :*

```
class HttpResponseTest(HttpResponse):
    def __init__(self, redirect_to):
        super(HttpResponseTest, self).__init__()
        self['Location'] = iri_to_uri(redirect_to)
        self.status_code = 403

def creation_permission_required(function):
    @wraps(function)
    @login_required
    def decorateur(request, *k, **a):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username__iexact=request.user.username)
        if user.is_superuser or user.get_profile().creation:
            return function(request, *k, **a)
        else:
            return HttpResponseTest(reverse("non_autorise"))# <--- PROBLEM
    return decorateur
    return function
```

Comment: Do you want to redirect to the view "non_autorise" or do you want to have a status code of 302? You can't have both.

Comment: I can't ? Because that's exactly what I want : 403 code + redirection

Comment: The probleme is not anymore about the question I ask, so I start a new question which are more precise about what I want : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324909/redirection-403-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a 403 response, you can raise a [PermissionDenied](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.PermissionDenied) exception in your decorator if you are using Django 1.4. Alternatively, you can return a [HttpResponseForbidden](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseForbidden) in your decorator. You will also have to build [a custom login_required decorator](http://blog.y3xz.com/post/11732029434/django-login-required-decorator-with-403).

Comment: I tried to use HttpResponseForbidden, but couldn't get any content. I just edit my post to explain that

Answer (score 1):

```
self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 403)
```

Comment: Or am I missing something here?

Comment: In fact the problem really come with the decorator which use an HttpResponseRedirect() But I don't know how to do the same thing without it

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and solved it by instructing the test get() to follow the redirect using `follow=True`. Using BlueMagma's example it would look something like this:

```
for url in self.url_creation:
    r = c.get(reverse(url['url'], args=url['args']), follow=True)
    self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 403)      # <--- SECOND PROBLEM NO MORE!!!
```

Hope this helps someone else!