# Redirection + 403 error

Tags: django, redirect, http-status-code-403, http-error

I am searching for a way to have something like that :

```
return HttpResponseForbiddenRedirect(reverse("view_name"))
```

an HttpResponse which redirect to a view (with its name) but still throw a 403 error

I tried to do something like that :

```
class HttpResponseForbiddenRedirect(HttpResponse):
    def __init__(self, redirect_to):
        super(HttpResponseForbiddenRedirect, self).__init__()
        self['Location'] = iri_to_uri(redirect_to)
        self.status_code = 403
```

But it didn't work. For some reason I don't understand, I don't get any content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this :

```
from app_name.views import my_view

....
    retour = my_views(request)
    return HttpResponseForbidden(retour)
```

It is in fact quite simple

And so I get the 403 error + the page I wanna load

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't work because you can't have a 403 response that is *also* acted upon as if it is a 302 response.

The [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) tells browsers how to handle certain status codes, and so a browser getting a 403 won't bother to look to see if there's a Location header in the way that it would do with a 302.

If you want to redirect someone from X to Y because they're not allowed to see X, then just issue a standard 302, and do something like setting a message (using django.contrib.messages) to inform the user of why they've been redirected, or redirect them to a page that explains what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the idea behind HTTP status codes. Redirect is being made with HTTP code 301/302. So you cannot make redirect and return 403 at the same time. It is simply not a redirect, if there is no 301/302 code returned.

I don't get it why you need this, but you can always make a view like:

```
def my403view(request): # e.g. /403.html
    return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

and to do your redirect with:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("403.html"))
```

This will redirect(with code 302) to "my403view", and it will return 403.